# Is it possible to capture property access in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, properties, aop

I want to be able to provide a JavaScript function that will be called whenever any property of a specified object is being queried or updated. Is that possible, if so, how?

To give a simple example, if I have `obj = { a:3 }`, I want to have some function called whenever any code queries `obj.a`, and be able to return whatever I want instead of its current value, e.g. 4 instead of 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easy, you can use `Object.prototype.defineProperty`. more on it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty).

To answer your question:

```
var obj = {};
Object.defineProperty(obj, "a", {
    get: function() {console.log("I've been accessed"); return 5;//or whatever value}
});
console.log(obj.a)
```

**[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6eatp/)**

**Update**

The above can be shorthanded.

```
Object.prototype.addMonitoredGetter = function(property, value, callback) {
    Object.defineProperty(this, property, {
        writable: false,
        get: function() {callback(); return this[property]
    };
};
```

And the callback here could be the monitoring function. Of course, needs default params and checks, but it should do the trick.

Comment: You unfortunately can't have both an internal value and getters/setters, so your setter code will fail miserably, as it will recursively call itself until the browser either crashes or the code simply fails.

Comment: Yes, alone it will allow monitoring of property access.  Having said that though, it might be annoying for numerous properties.

Comment: This sounds interesting, I will experiment on it... What I want to do is to have a property available but defer calculating its value until it is required (if it is required at all). Yes of course, this can be done using a standard getter function, but I am using an existing library which relies on directly querying a property, thus this approach. Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

There's a watch method available for Firefox...

```
o.watch("p", function(...)
```

http://jsfiddle.net/NTc52/

Comment: That is great! Unfortunately it is non-standard, and not even supported in other modern JS engines such as Chrome.